# Vue lifecycle hook - conditionally prevent creation

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Is there a way to prevent component creation during the lifecycle hook? For example:

```
beforeCreated() {
    //checking value from vuex store
    if (this.$store.state.attendeesCount >= this.$store.state.maxAttendees) {
        //prevent further propagation, don't create an instance of component
    }
}
```

The case is, I have a parent component with multiple child components which contain form for creating attendees (1 component = 1 attendee). I would like to prevent the creation of the child component if the seminar is already fully booked.

Update:
Parent component is base component for dozen of multirow form components and I didn't want to perform checks there to keep it as abstract as possible.

Comment: Why wouldn't you do that using `v-if` on the child component's tag in the parent component?

Comment: I think you could call `this.$destroy()` but that is arguably not a clean/idiomatic solution. Probably a better way would be to use a `v-if` on the child components instead.

Comment: @Constantin Groß Yeah, that would be the easiest way, but I would like to avoid modifying parent component. It is like the placeholder for many other multirow forms in the rest of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of actually preventing creation of child component during the lifecycle hook, I have emitted custom event once the condition is met. Parent component listens to this custom event, and deletes child component instance.

Child:

```
beforeCreate() {
    if (this.$store.state.attendeesCount >= 
    this.$store.state.maxAttendees) {
        this.$emit('preventCreation', {message: 'No more places'})
    }
}
```

Parent:

```
<template>
    <component v-for="(item, index) in components"
         @preventCreation="preventCreation(index, $event)"
    ...
    >
    </component>
...
</template>
...
methods(){
    preventCreation(index, payload){
        this.components.splice(index, 1)
        alert(payload.msg)
    }
}
```